# Is there a cleaner way to write this boolean comparison in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

The instructions for this assignment are:

> We pass in 2 boolean inputs, cold and rainy.
>
> You should output a single string: ('cold' or 'warm') ' and ' ('rainy'
>   or 'dry') based on these inputs.
>
> ('cold' or 'warm') means you should use on of the two words, depending
>   on the input boolean value.
>
> for example False, True = 'warm and rainy'

The code I have put is:

```
# Get our boolean values from the command line
import sys
isCold= sys.argv[1] == 'True'
isRainy= sys.argv[2] == 'True'

# Your code goes here

condition = ""
if (isCold):
  condition += "cold"
else:
  condition += "warm"

if (isRainy):
  condition += " and rainy"
else:
  condition += " and dry"

print(condition)
```

The code is correct and outputs what it is supposed to, but I'm wondering is there a cleaner way to write this? I feel like there is but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine conditional expressions with Python 3.6's [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to build the string with a single line of code:

```
condition = f"{'cold' if isCold else 'warm'} and {'rainy' if isRainy else 'dry'}"
```

In Python 2, the [`%` string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) can work as well:

```
condition = "%s and %s" % (
    'cold' if isCold else 'warm',
    'rainy' if isRainy else 'dry'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! One issue I ran into on a separate file to practice this is when I type: print(f"{'cold' if isCold else 'warm'} and {'rainy' if isRainy else 'dry'}"), I get a syntax error with the arrow pointing at the last double quote just before the parenthesis. I know it might not be easy to see the error without seeing the rest of the code but I don't want to make a whole new thread over this, I was wondering if you can see the error with just this information and tell me what's wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Syntax error is most likely due to your version of Python. `f`-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: Aha! That's what it is. The python version I'm running is 3.4.3

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional expressions.

```
condition += "cold" if isCold else "warm"
condition += " and " + ("rainy" if isRainy else "dry")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend first using ternary expressions to get the string values for cold/warm and rainy/dry:

```
coldText = 'cold' if isCold else 'warm'
rainyText = 'rainy' if isRainy else 'dry'
```

Then use [string interpolation](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) to construct your final string, so that form and content are separated:

```
finalText = '%s and %s' % (coldText, rainyText)
print(finalText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use dictionaries:

```
condition = {True: 'cold', False: 'warm'}[isCold] + ' and ' + {True: 'rainy', False: 'dry'}[isRainy]
```

Less pythonic, because less explicit:

one can use coercion of `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` and use it as index.

```
condition = ['warm', 'cold'][isCold] + ' and ' + ['dry', 'rainy'][isRainy]
```

I use coercion of `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` often when e.g. counting `True` values in a boolean list. (`sum()` over the list).